# Disable Windows Firewall notifications via registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry, firewall

How to disable Windows Firewall notifications via registry?

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> How to disable Windows Firewall notifications via registry?

You can disable taskbar balloon notifications by doing the following steps:

> 1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER
> 2. Locate the following subkey:
>
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
> 3. Right-click the right side pane, create a new DWORD value, and then name it **EnableBalloonTips**.
> 4. Double-click **EnableBalloonTips**, and then give it a value of **0**.
> 5. Close Registry Editor
> 6. Log off Windows, and then log back on.

Source: [How do I disable balloon tips in the notification area in Windows XP or Vista?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307729/how-do-i-disable-balloon-tips-in-the-notification-area-in-windows-xp-o)

Answer (score 2):

You can either change this setting directly...

- In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\DomainProfile` set `REG_DWORD` value `DisableNotifications` to `1`
- In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\PrivateProfile` set `REG_DWORD` value `DisableNotifications` to `1`
- In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\PublicProfile` set `REG_DWORD` value `DisableNotifications` to `1`

...or set it as policy...:

- In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile` set `REG_DWORD` value `DisableNotifications` to `1`
- In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PrivateProfile` set `REG_DWORD` value `DisableNotifications` to `1`
- In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile` set `REG_DWORD` value `DisableNotifications` to `1`

Comment: unfortunatelly that doesn't help.. I still see these notifications.. tried many things..

Answer (score -2):

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "EnableBalloonTips" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f