# Turn off firewall notifications Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firewall, notifications

I am trying to disable firewall notifications on Windows 10. I am talking about the notifications that pop up in the bottom right corner balloon-like icon.

I followed a few steps I looked up on the internet, but it didn't work.
You can see what I did in this picture below (I merged two windows in one picture).

[image: notifications]

My next attempt would be [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1226355/disable-windows-firewall-notifications-via-registry) answer via windows registry, but this seems a bit too drastic as (I think) it disables balloon notifications completely.

Is there anything else I can try? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should disable Security and Maintenance notifications. Sort notifications by Name in Settings > System > Notifications

Comment: I tried what you said that but still getting the notification to turn the firewall on...

Comment: The firewall is part of Windows Defender.  You can [turn off](https://www.wisecleaner.com/how-to/119-how-to-turn-off-windows-defender-in-windows-10.html) Defender, but you have to install another antivirus. [This](https://www.kaspersky.com/free-antivirus) is a good and free antivirus.